# Clojure - Parsing Elasticsearch query response and extracting values

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, clojure, edn

I'm looking to parse an Elasticsearch query response and convert it into my own format. The response may have nested buckets and the level of nesting will be variable for each query. This is is a simplified version of the result:

```
{:bucket-aggregation
 {:buckets
  [{:key "outer_bucket"
    :bucket-aggregation
    {:buckets
     [{:key "inner_bucket_1"
       :bucket-aggregation
       {:buckets
        [{:key 1510657200000, :sum {:value 25}}
         {:key 1510660800000, :sum {:value 50}}]}}
      {:key "inner_bucket_2"
       :bucket-aggregation
       {:buckets
        [{:key 1510657200000, :sum {:value 30}}
         {:key 1510660800000, :sum {:value 35}}]}}
      {:key "inner_bucket_3"
       :bucket-aggregation
       {:buckets
        [{:key 1510657200000, :sum {:value 40}}
         {:key 1510660800000, :sum {:value 45}}]}}]}}]}}
```

I would like to extract the :value and :key into a structure like this:

```
[{:key ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_1" 1510657200000], :value 25}
 {:key ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_1" 1510660800000], :value 50}
 {:key ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_2" 1510657200000], :value 30}
 {:key ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_2" 1510660800000], :value 35}
 {:key ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_3" 1510657200000], :value 40}
 {:key ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_3" 1510660800000], :value 45}]
```

Any suggestions on how I should go about this?

edit: simplified the desired format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way to do it using `clojure.walk/postwalk` that doesn't assume a fixed nesting depth i.e. it'll work with more shallow or deeply nested inputs.

```
(clojure.walk/postwalk
  (fn [v]
    (cond
      ;; deepest case, pull up sum value
      (and (map? v) (:key v) (:sum v))
      {:key [(:key v)], :value (get-in v [:sum :value])}
      ;; pull up unnecessary buckets map wrapper
      (and (map? v) (:buckets v))
      (flatten (:buckets v))
      ;; select outer bucket + inner buckets
      (and (map? v) (:key v) (:bucket-aggregation v))
      (let [outer-key (:key v)
            buckets (:bucket-aggregation v)]
        (map #(update % :key (fn [k] (into [outer-key] k))) buckets))
      ;; pass-through
      :else v))
  (:bucket-aggregation result))
=>
({:key ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_1" 1510657200000], :value 25}
 {:key ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_1" 1510660800000], :value 50}
 {:key ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_2" 1510657200000], :value 30}
 {:key ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_2" 1510660800000], :value 35}
 {:key ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_3" 1510657200000], :value 40}
 {:key ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_3" 1510660800000], :value 45})
```

Comment: Switching to this as the accepted answer instead, as this does not require an extra dependency, but thanks anyway @cfrick

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to add library, this is how you can do it with [specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter):

```
; assume your data there is in `(def data ...)`
(use 'com.rpl.specter)
(select [:bucket-aggregation :buckets ALL (collect-one :key) ; TODO: extract that reoccuring path
         :bucket-aggregation :buckets ALL (collect-one :key) 
         :bucket-aggregation :buckets ALL (collect-one :key) 
         :sum :value] 
        data)
; => [["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_1" 1510657200000 25]
; =>  ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_1" 1510660800000 50]
; =>  ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_2" 1510657200000 30]
; =>  ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_2" 1510660800000 35]
; =>  ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_3" 1510657200000 40]
; =>  ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_3" 1510660800000 45]]
```

From here on it's just some shaping:

```
(map (fn [[k1 k2 k3 v]] {:keys [k1 k2 k3] :value v}) (select ...))
; => ({:keys ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_1" 1510657200000], :value 25}
; =>  {:keys ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_1" 1510660800000], :value 50}
; =>  {:keys ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_2" 1510657200000], :value 30}
; =>  {:keys ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_2" 1510660800000], :value 35}
; =>  {:keys ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_3" 1510657200000], :value 40}
; =>  {:keys ["outer_bucket" "inner_bucket_3" 1510660800000], :value 45})
```